# How do I say "back in the day"?

Tags: translation

I'm looking for an expression that I can use to express "back in the day, when I was young, we used to...". Something like the German *damals*. I'm not sure if I can use *pasintece* or maybe *tiatempe* or something similar. How would you translate it?

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps more a question about English, but as a native speaker, I'm not sure what "back in the day" adds to the actual meaning of your example phrase. Why not just say "when I was young, we used to..."? I'm more used to hearing the phrase "back in the day" used by itself. (Back in the day, we didn't even have indoor plumbing.)

I would just say *kiam mi estis juna* or *kiam mi estis malgranda*. You could also say *pasinte* or *antaŭe* if you wanted to be more vague, or *en tiu tempo, kiam mi estis juna* if you wanted to be more wordy.

Comment: I think it's more of a style thing, how one expresses oneself. In German, I'd say "damals" to show that it is a long time ago. Maybe "a long long time ago" would be a better translation.   Maybe I could use a better example sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I think *Pasintece...* ("In the past...") should be fine. *Antaŭe* is "formerly" and *tiutempe* is "at that time"; *tiatempe* is more like "at those times".

More ruminative versions are *Malnovtempe...* ("In the old days..."), *Tiuepoke...* ("At that point in history..."), or *En la iamo...* ("In days of yore...")

*En tempo jam de longe pasinta* is an opening to a *Fabelo*, but more often those confine themselves to throwing in *iam*.

Comment: What is the *-ec-* doing there in *pasintece*? Is that a quality?

Comment: It's referring to *la pasinteco* in the sense of *la paseo* ("the past"). Compare *Pasintece, li uzis la bluan pordon por eniri* ("In the past, he used the blue door to enter") with *Pasinte, li uzis la bluan pordon* ("Having passed/In the past, he used the blue door").

Comment: Very interesting. I'll see if I can roll all the thoughts I have on this into a coherent question and post it. Thanks.